# Unexpected result in C program

Tags: c

Can you please explain the output of this C program? I guess that the problem is with the stack getting corrupt during `printf("%d\n",t);`  function call because I'm pushing a `float` but reading an `int`. I'm not sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{ 
    long x; 
    float t; 
    scanf("%f",&t); 
    printf("%d\n",t); 
    x=30;
    printf("%f\n",x); 
    { 
        x=9;
        printf("%f\n",x); 
        { 
            x=10;
            printf("%f\n",x); 
        } 
        printf("%f\n",x); 
    } 
    x==9;
    printf("%f\n",x); 

}
```

And the output

```
$ ./a.out 
20.39
0
20.389999
20.389999
20.389999
20.389999
20.389999
$
```

Comment: You need to compile your code with more compiler warnings enabled, and heed the warnings it does give you (before posting the code to SO).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: As I read the Q, he knows he's doing it wrong but would like to understand what actually happens. He should've been more explicit though, and included compiler/platform info.

Answer (score 9):

What happens is that you lie to the compiler ... first you tell it you are going to send an `int` to printf but you send a float instead, and then you tell it you are going to send a `double` but you send a `long` instead.

**Don't do that. Don't lie to the compiler.**

You have invoked ***Undefined Behaviour***. Anything can happen. Your program might corrupt the stack; it might output what you expect; it might make lemon juice come out of the USB port; it might make [demons fly out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html); ...

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format specifier to print long. Use format specifier `%ld` instead.
[Results](http://ideone.com/s5ERm)

```
printf("%f\n",x);
     // ^ change this to %ld
```

Comment: i know it is wrong,I asked for explanation for the output.Thanks anyway.

Comment: usage of wrong format specifier can lead to anything as @Prasoon quote stated from the standard. Hence the result.

Answer (score 1):

What actually happens is:

- Your `float` is 4 bytes, your `long` is 4 bytes, your `double` is 8 bytes.
- You pass a `float` through ellipsis - it gets converted to a `double`. 8 bytes on stack.
- You pass a `long` through ellipsis - 4 bytes on stack.
- `printf` parses 8 bytes on stack (`float` specifier) as a `double`. This `double` will consist of the "important" part of the old `double` on stack, and a slight variation in the least significant part (your `long`).
- Default `%f` output truncates the value, you don't see the variation.

Change all your `%f` to e.g. `%.20f` to see how the `long` affects the `double`.

Comment: On AMD64 the first eight `float` arguments are passed through SSE registers, so the `long` won't overwrite even part of it.

Comment: @aaz: The behavior matches x86, so I'm doing a bad thing and assuming :)

Comment: – It matches AMD64, so I'm assuming too :) The `%.20f` result will be different though.

Comment: @aaz: Are registers used for ellipsis on amd64/gcc? Learn something new every day :P

Comment: – Yep. The only difference with ellipsis is that AL contains an upper bound on the number of SSE registers used for arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%d\n",t);`

Using incorrect format specifier in printf invokes undefined behaviour.

Use `%f` for printing `float` and `double` and `%ld` for printing long

C99 clearly says (wrt `printf` and `fprintf`)

> If a conversion speciﬁcation is invalid, the behavior is undeﬁned. If any argument is
>   not  the  correct  type  for  the  corresponding  conversion  speciﬁcation,  the  behavior  is
>   undeﬁned.