# Value assigned to s variable when uses %d instead %f

Tags: c, programming-languages

I assume output to be 8 but the line s=a+b assign value 5 to s variable not sum of a+b. I know that I am using %d instead of %f.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void summ(int, int);
int main(){
    int a = 3, b = 5;
    summ(a, b);
    return 0;
}
void summ(int a, int b){
    float s;
    s = a + b;
    printf("%d", s);
}
```

Comment: (1) Post code, not images of it. (2) You use the wrong format specifier for printf, the behavior is undefined, so there is no point analyzing it. Fix your program.

Comment: Do you normally give your compiler a jpg image of a program?

Comment: s is float and you are using %d for printing this. It should be %f.

Comment: Here is your problem: You need to compile your programs with warnings enabled. Then the compiler will tell you that you have a type mismatch in the printf statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unexpected result in c program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402928/unexpected-result-in-c-program)

Comment: The first problem is trying to print a `float` value using a `int` format specifier.  Suggest: `printf( "%f\n", s);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any old format specifier in a `printf()`. It always has to match the type of the variable you are passing in. If you want to print a value as another type, you have to convert it first, then print the converted value. So either this has to be:

```
void summ(int a, int b)
{
    float s;
    s = a + b;
    printf( "%f\n", s );
}
```

or

```
void summ(int a, int b)
{
    int s;
    s = a + b;
    printf( "%d\n", s );
}
```

In the case of your sum function, you won't see a noticeable difference (except that `%d` does not print a ".0000" after the number, but you could have suppressed that by adding a length of `0` to the fraction of your `%f` by writing it as `%.0f`).

OTOH, if you have a division:

```
void divv(int a, int b)
{
    float s;
    s = a / b;
    printf( "%f\n", s );
}
```

the CPU will perform a (often faster) integer division. That means that `3 / 5` (which would be `0.6`) just gives you `0` because it didn't bother calculating the fraction. The compiler doesn't look at the type of variable an expression is *assigned* to, so it doesn't see that it could actually store the fraction. It just looks at the *operands* of the operator, which are both `int`, calculates an `int`, and expands it into a `float`. So if you wanted a precise result, you'd have to do:

```
void divv(int a, int b)
{
    float s;
    s = (float)a / (float)b;
    printf( "%f\n", s );
}
```

because as soon as one of the arguments is a `float`, it will perform a floating point division and also calculate the fraction.

Answer (score 0):

here is a possible version of the code that cleanly compiles and performs the desired functionality.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void summ(int, int);

int main( void )
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    summ(a, b);
    return 0;
}  // end function: main


void summ(int a, int b)
{
    float s;
    s = (float)(a + b);
    //printf("%d", s);
    printf( "%f\n", s );
}  // end function: summ
```

The output from the above code is:

```
8.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but why we need to cast a+b to float , can't it be done implicitly means after adding values of a and b and then convert them to float by compiler and assigned to s.

Comment: @PRAVEENKUMAR,  Sure it 'can' be converted implicitly.  However, if you actually enable the warnings, especially the `-Wconversion` warnings, then the compiler will raise a warning message at each such 'implicit' conversion.   Best to force the issue rather than depending on the compiler to do the right thing.  And if you really want to be explicit, then this function is also available `s = float( a + b );`

Comment: `float( n )` is not a function. It is a C++ constructor-syntax-style typecast. As such, it will not work unless you are compiling your code as C++ (either because your project is set up to compile C files as C++, or because your code actually resides in a .cp or .cpp file). Since the question is tagged as "C" only, this will likely not work for the OP.

Comment: @PRAVEENKUMAR The typecast is not needed. But if this code did a division instead, you'd have to typecast at least one of the arguments, because the result of an operation depends on its argument types. If you have `int / int` the CPU will perform a (often faster) integer division. That means that 3 / 5 (which would be 0.6) just gives you 0 because it didn't bother calculating the fraction. The compiler doesn't look at the type of variable an expression is assigned to, so it doesn't see that it could actually store the fraction. It just calculates an int and expands it into a float.

Comment: @uliwitness thanks

Comment: @user3629249 thanks